# Why can nameof not be used with alias-qualified types at the root level?

Tags: c#, nameof

Imagine a type at the root namespace level (could be in the default `global` space, or could potentially be an `extern alias`).

It appears that this type *cannot* be referred to via `nameof()`, when using the alias prefix. It works fine with `typeof`, and via `using` aliases (although `nameof` on a `using` alias yields the alias name, not the type name). The compiler objects with CS8083, "An alias-qualified name is not an expression."

But: is there a reason for this? is this trying to prevent some obscure problem scenario? or meet some specification minutae? or is it perhaps a compiler bug? I'm also fully content to note that we *shouldn't* usually declare types in the namespace root - `CA1050` is very right about this; but that's not the point here :)

Full example follows; note that in this example uses two projects for the `using` alias check, but that for simplicity everything involving `C` can just be ignored for a simple investigation.

```cs
extern alias foo;
using System;
using X = global::A;
using Y = global::FunWithNamespaces.B;
using Z = foo::C;

public class A { }

namespace FunWithNamespaces
{
    public class B { }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // oddness is on the lines marked ## CS8083

            // relative-qualified using typeof
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(X).Name); // A, expected
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Y).Name); // B, expected
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Z).Name); // C, expected
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).Name); // A
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(B).Name); // B
            // note: can't talk about C without using an alias qualifier or a using-alias
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(Console).Name); // Console

            // relative-qualified things using nameof
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(X)); // X; I'm on the fence about X vs A, but... whatever
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(Y)); // Y; I'm on the fence about Y vs B, but... whatever
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(Z)); // Z; I'm on the fence about Z vs C, but... whatever
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(A)); // A
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(B)); // B
            // note: can't talk about C without using an alias qualifier or a using-alias
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(Console)); // Console

            // alias-qualified things using typeof
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(global::A).Name); // A
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(global::FunWithNamespaces.B).Name); // B
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(foo::C).Name); // C
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(global::System.Console).Name); // Console

            // alias-qualified things using nameof
            // ??? Console.WriteLine(nameof(global::A)); // ## CS8083 An alias-qualified name is not an expression
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(global::FunWithNamespaces.B)); // B
            // ??? Console.WriteLine(nameof(foo::C)); // ## CS8083 An alias-qualified name is not an expression
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(global::System.Console)); // Console
        }
        
    }
}
```

where `C` is defined in a separate assembly and referenced with aliases specified as `foo`, and is simply:

```cs
public class C { }
```

---

Edit: in terms of the specification, this comes down to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#nameof-expressions, where a `nameof_expression` must be either a `simple_name` (which it isn't) or a `named_entity_target '.' identifier type_argument_list?` - so: for all cases that aren't a simple name, there **must** be a `.something` - but I guess the *underlying* question here is **why** must there be a `.something`, vs some other construction that permits `global::Foo`? For example:

```cs
nameof_expression
    : 'nameof' '(' named_entity ')'
    ;

named_entity
    : simple_name
    | named_entity_target '.' identifier type_argument_list?
    | qualified_alias_member type_argument_list?
    ;

named_entity_target
    : 'this'
    | 'base'
    | named_entity 
    | predefined_type 
    | qualified_alias_member
    ;
```

Comment: There seems to be some related discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/911

Comment: I think this is worthy of a github issue. It seems strange to say the least and potentially an obscure design decision worthy of an authoritive explanation. Edit ^^

Comment: Honestly, **if** anyone could answer that I'd expected Marc to do :D

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg that has been asserted but not demonstrated. It was certainly a perfectly valid expression a few lines above :) the fact that the Microsoft.Whatever example passes means nothing: that could *also* resolve to be a namespace rather than a type

Comment: This specific issue is also [mentioned](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/911#discussioncomment-71972) on GitHub. A reply [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/911#discussioncomment-71973) says: it's not a valid expression syntactically (added before Marc's comment). Update: Maybe it will be fixed along with [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/702) proposal filed by Jon Skeet, which seems to be the restriction of the same expression syntax limitation. But I can't tell why `global::C` is valid though. Maybe add a comment to the GitHub issue.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I don't think that proposal of Jon Skeet's affects this?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg in terms of it being a valid `nameof_expression` - the real question is "why is that rule like it is?" - not "why is the compiler following the rule?"; I've clarified with citations

Comment: @canton7: [this](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/702#discussioncomment-69700) comment suggests that they are related. I cannot confirm it though.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks; opined :)

Comment: also linking for context: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1590

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to underlying question

if you came here for compile-time desision - there is no way at this moment. It is an expected behavior from compilator side as result of expression compilation.

#### Quick runtime solution

`(typeof(f::SomeCustomClassName)).Name` instead of `nameof(f::SomeCustomClassName)`

### Explanation

Now lets see again to **nameof_expression** [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11720-nameof-expressions)

```cs
nameof_expression = 'nameof' '(' named_entity ')'
```

where **named_entity** is

```cs
named_entity = named_entity_target ('.' identifier type_argument_list?)*
```

And lets look again to calling class name.
In common variant without aliases we got:
`nameof(SomeCustomClassName)` that unfolds to `nameof(ConsoleApp1.SomeCustomClassName)`

That matches `named_entity_target.identifier`.

But the alias `nameof(f::SomeCustomClassName)`...

From specification

```cs
named_entity_target
    : simple_name
    | 'this'
    | 'base'
    | predefined_type 
    | qualified_alias_member
    ;
```

Is **qualified_alias_member** so *named_entity_target = qualified_alias_member*

So **nameof_expression** unfolds to

```cs
qualified_alias_member ('.' identifier type_argument_list?)*
```

Lets have a look to **qualified_alias_member** [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#138-qualified-alias-member):

```cs
qualified_alias_member
    : identifier '::' identifier type_argument_list?
    ;
```

According to all of this we have

```cs
identifier '::' identifier ('.' identifier type_argument_list?)*
```

That does not match to `nameof(f::SomeCustomClassName)`
Thats why it is incorrect for compilator.
Thats why it need for *dot*
`nameof(f::SomeCustomClassName.SomeCustomClassName2)`

it is not a bug. It is miscalculation from expression creators or porposive limitation.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the `named_entity_target` etc in the question;  I guess the real question is (per your last line): "is this an intentional limitation? If so, what intent? If not, can the limitation be removed?"

Comment: Only if microsoft decides it matters. But current state of work with aliases is unfortunate and most of coders doesn't use them because this reason too. If IDE's developers will support better approach to work with aliases, only then something can change when more people pay attention to this problem. In .net core issue tracker no info about changes with aliases so not in the coming years.

Comment: UPD. I mean that changes on compiler side no issue opened. But a lot of issues of work with aliases from IDE. So all as I thought.

Answer (score -1):

The resolution of the expression is done during compilation, hence the CSxxx compilation errors. So the operator **nameof()** has no effect during runtime.

Plus, it might use *.Net Reflection* to get the name of the value that you gave as parameter. Therefore to resolve a type via reflection, the compiler needs the "full path" of the member (i.e from the namespace to it).

Comment: Nobody said anything about runtime; and an alias-qualified name **is** a "full path"